# How to share methods between unrelated components in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm probably missing some concept of VueJS so I need help on this one. I made an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wood-fe4kd) to make my question more clear. Let's say I have some multipurpose component like [modal](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wood-fe4kd?file=/src/components/modal.vue) window. I'm grabbing data from Vuex.

`./components/modal.vue`

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    modalClose() {
      this.$store.commit("modalClose");
    },
  },
  computed: {
    body() {
      return this.$store.state.modal.body;
    },
    footer() {
      return this.$store.state.modal.footer;
    },
    show() {
      return this.$store.state.modal.show;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="wrap" @click.self="modalClose" v-if="show">
    <div id="modal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-body" v-html="this.body">body</div>
      <div class="modal-footer" v-html="this.footer">footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
/* whatever */
</style>
```

And I have [another component](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wood-fe4kd?file=/src/components/persons.vue) which set Vuex data and use my modal component to show the data. And it works fine - it presents the data. But at some point I need to work with the data inside the modal window and this is where I'm losing it.

`./components/persons.vue`

```
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      persons: [
        { name: "John Johnson", id: 1 },
        { name: "David Lynch", id: 2 },
        { name: "Marshall Attack", id: 3 },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showModal: function (person) {
      this.$store.commit("modal", {
        body: "Name: " + person.name,
        footer: `<a href="#" person-id="${person.id}">Add</a>`,
      });
    },
    addPerson: function (id) {
      // how to trigger this function with "Add" button?
      console.log("Success! Person " + id + " was added!");
    },
  },
};
</script>
<template>
  <div id="page1">
    <div v-for="person in persons" :key="person.id">
      {{ person.name }}
      <a href="#" @click="showModal(person)"> Open modal </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In this example you can see method `addPerson`. It belongs to `persons.vue` and it suppose to be executed (argument required) with click on "Add" button inside the modal window. So, I have two questions:

1. How can I do it?
2. Am I populating bad practices?

**P.S.** I read about `$emit` but I didn't have any luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

I did not fully understand your issue, but the basic idea is that various components can commit data to your store. And also dispatch actions to store. And store itself should be able to handle actions like `addPerson` using the data that is already committed. Usually in a case of multiple components that "create" an entry, your store (or a store module) would have

- a state with relevant entries, for example in general CRUD it's usually an array of `people` and `newPerson` where you store the temporary entries
- mutations that allow editing some of that data
- a getter `canAddPerson` that computes if you have enough data in the `newPerson` object to actually create a new person
- an action `addPerson` that uses `newPerson`, optionally does an AJAX POST, commits the new person to be included in the people array and clears the `newPerson` fields.

A caveat that I occasionally fall for is that this `newPerson` shouldn't be `{}`, it should instead be defined with all the fields `{name: null, height: null, ...}` otherwise the fields will not be reactive.

> Am I populating bad practices?

You should not be putting HTML in the store, just data.

P.S. The answer to the question in title is "mixins", but I don't think that's what you've asked in the question body.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Vue so I might put something wrong. `Add` button is just a random name for the button. What I really want it to understand how can i trigger `addPerson` function with click inside modal window.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the `addPerson` function should be an action in your store (see Vuex actions). And then you just add an `@click="$store.dispatch('addPerson')"` attribute to the button and it's called.

Comment: absolutely, do NOT put html into the store, +1

Comment: Is there any convention i can read to learn more?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to skin the cat here.

1. Modal component writes its own data to the store.

Since the modal already reads its data from the store, you could also set the store values directly from the modal.  Create a new method that does this.  The benefit here is the modal can read and write its own data.  The downside is the modal is now tied to a certain type of data in your app and is not generally reusable.

2. From `persons.vue` with [`$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event):

Your modal should `$emit` when a certain event happens, e.g. when the user clicks "Add".  Wherever you have that link defined, add `@click="$emit('add', whateverDataYouWantToReturn)"` to it.  Then in the parent component, listen for the event with `@add="addPerson($event)"` when you use the modal.  The benefit here is you don't necessarily need to use the store; you can pass data to the modal as `props` and catch the events using `$emit`.

3. Using a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot) on the modal:

Whenever you use the modal in your parent template, you can insert whatever visual content you need inside the modal as supplied to the modal's slot.  This has the advantage of keeping the modal component generally reusable while also allowing you to call methods on the parent.

Comment: I forked demo code and implemented your first suggestion like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-flower-36fcv In this implementation I store buttons of modal window as an objects in Vuex store and I listen to click events inside `modal.vue` with `handleClick` method. Is that what what you mean? It has limited functionality but it works.

Comment: Also I don't see how we can use `slot` (suggestion #3) in this case. I specifically pointed out that two (or more) components suppose to be unrelated.

Comment: you're doing a lot of unnecessary work in the `footer` computed property that can easily be handled with a `v-for` directly in the template.  just add the `@click=""` directly to the element you're rendering with `v-for`.

Comment: components with slots are perfect for wrapping generic/unrelated content that needs parent scope. e.g. your modal template could simply be `<template><div class="modal"><slot></slot></div></template>`, and let the parent use it with `<modal>your content here</modal>`

Answer (score 0):

Looking bad hook.

Normally:
modal.vue be inside in persons.vue
Then after modal show must be false in data properties (modalShow:false)

And you must send "props" to modal component if show modal with selected data.

Comment: Actually I thought about it, but then I read bootstrap documentation and it states that: "Modals use position: fixed, which can sometimes be a bit particular about its rendering. Whenever possible, place your modal HTML in a top-level position to avoid potential interference from other elements. You’ll likely run into issues when nesting a .modal within another fixed element."

Comment: "You’ll likely run into issues when nesting a .modal within another fixed element." Its not for status. Modals must be inside parent component.Like Main Component->Modal Component. So data hook must be main to modal with props. Research props in documentation Vue then after you understand me